# Angualrjs dropdown select box reading Json object text

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-service

what I am trying to do is to make a dropdown selection that read the text from the json data. I somehow cannot read the value and I am not sure why.

Here is my code

My dropdown box:

```
   <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <b class="input-label">Claim Type:</b>
                <select ng-model="claimType" required>
                  <option value="Select claim" title="Select Claim" selected disabled>Claim Type</option>
                  <option ng-repeat="claim in claimType " value="{{claim.value}}"
                          ng-selected="{{claim.value== claimType}}">
                          {{claim.text}} 
                              </option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
```

My Json Object

```
 angular.module('app')
        .factory('WebApi', function () {

            var claimType = [{
                value: "Car",
                text: "Car",
            }, {
                value: "Boat",
                text: "Boat",
            }, {
                value: "Others",
                text: "Others"
            }]
        })
 //Display 50 items randomly
   var tempData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                    var selectedClaimType = claimType[Math.floor((Math.random() * claimType.length))];
                   tempData.push({
                        claimType: selectedClaimType.text,
                    })
                };
            return {
              getClaimTypes: function () {

                    return selectedClaimType.text;
                },
            }
```

In my controller, I called

```
$scope.claimType = WebApi.getClaimTypes();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) to help with managing a select list.

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
    <b class="input-label">Claim Type:</b>
    <select ng-model="claimType" required
      ng-options="transport.text for transport in traffic">
      <option value="" title="Select Claim" selected disabled>Claim Type</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

This will bind the selected `transport` to the `claimType`.  If you want `claimType` to be assigned the value of `transport.value` instead, you can do:

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
    <b class="input-label">Claim Type:</b>
    <select ng-model="claimType" required
      ng-options="transport.text as transport.value for transport in traffic">
      <option value="" title="Select Claim" selected disabled>Claim Type</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Comment: thank you for your quick respond, what if I have something like this? I notice that I cannot do that because I have the random property, do you have any idea how to fix this? I need that for loops because I want to display 50 dummy data. Thanks

Comment: your code shows you creating a `tempData` array and pushing some values into it, but I don't see where you were using that "random" array in the selectlist binding....

Comment: in fact, your factory doesn't seem like it is returning what you expect; you *want* an array, but what you actually return is a single value.